# Best practices for calling multiple APIs and manipulating data before showing it to user?

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, api

I am building a web application that makes use of multiple API's (Google Maps, Weather APIs, and more). I am using Python + Flask on the backend, and Javascript (probably with React, I have not decided yet) on Front end.

The application will take the results of these various API query's and then give the user a simple, summarized result, which involves a fair amount of calculations and conditional logic based on the API response.

What the best practice to do this?

If I do all the API calls on the client side, and I deal with calculations and such there too, that feels cumbersome.

If I do it all on the backend, the calls are not asyncronous and so I am worried the calls might take a while. Though in my use case a 2-3 second wait is probably acceptable as long as there is a "Loading" message. This is what I currently have (halfway through writing all the API calls and the needed calculations)

I could also do the API calls on the client, pass it to the server for calculations, and then sent the results back to the front end. Not sure if that's a practical solution or if it would really solve anything.

Comment: API calls can be asynchronous on server side as well

Comment: How so? Is that possible using Python and Flask? I'm sure it's possible with some other languages but that's not what I'm doing here.

Comment: `Though in my use case a 2-3 second wait is probably acceptable as long as there is a "Loading" message` then what's worrying you?

Comment: 1. "Probably acceptable" is still far from ideal. I want to cut down the wait as much as possible. 2. It could be even longer than that, which is not acceptable

Comment: sounds all very theoretical. Did you get any evidence that you "already" need to improve something that was not yet implemented?

Comment: I have implemented it, entirely in the backend. There is currently about a 2 second delay. I am worried about it getting worse as I add more to it (more API's and calculations/data processing on their responses). Currently using 5 external APIs, will be at least 8 or 9 by the time I am done

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that I currently am going down this route and am half complete.

Comment: Does results of different API calls need to be "summarized" together? Or every API call will be "summarized" separately?

Comment: Some are dependent on eachother, some are not. I guess I can batch most of them together onto the backend to provide one summary. This would mean having about 5/6 API calls in the backend (already taking ~2 seconds) and the remaining 3 or 4 could be client side

Comment: To clarify the earlier "depenent on eachother" - the get requests for some APIs depend on the responses of others.

Comment: Instead, you can create separated endpoints on your backend for every independent summary. Then client/javascript will call them asynchronously.

Comment: Can you clarify what endpoints means in this context? Is that just the route that the client will call on my server? So one call to the server to get the 6-API summary, and 3 calls to the server the other 3 APIs. Yes?

Comment: Yes, different routes for the client or same route with different parameters.

Comment: Python has concurrent IO. Please clarify, what exactly can't be done asynchronously on server?

Comment: Python 3.5+ has excellent support for async operations (see the asyncio standard library module). Flask is not async (i.e. handles one request at a time) but within one request you can freely use Python's async features. But most people using Flask farm out async tasks to an external job queue. There are also Flask-like async web frameworks like Sanic. In your case, I'd find a way to perform all API requests concurrently/asynchronously from the backend. How to do that depends on the library you're using.

Comment: I did not know that was possible. I will look into that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a server to manage and call external APIs then combine the responses as necessary and return them to the client.

- You shouldn't be hijacking your clients resources to call all these services and process results depending on how intensive it is. You also don't know what kind of connection your client has, what takes you a few seconds on a good connection could be significantly longer.
- You can't guarantee your client can access all the various API endpoints which requires more work to fallback gracefully. Corporate environments are a good example where this is common.
- You may be able to take advantage of caching some calls across users.

The general goal should be to minimize the number of requests and amount of data transferred. Third party requests should also be minimized unless they can reduce the amount of data transferred or provide similar benefit (ie CDNs).

Comment: If the 3rd party endpoints need a kind of auth token, managing the 3rd party calls on the server side would also ensure confidentiality.